# Disconnecting PuTTY with Amazon Web Services EC2

Tags: bash, putty, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, r

I am using `PuTTY` to submit a `bash` file to `Amazon Web Services EC2` to run `R` files.  The cursor in `PuTTY` disappears when I submit the `bash` file and does not reappear until all of the `R` files have finished running (currently ~40 minutes later, but eventually 10-20 hours later).

I have never seen this before when using clusters at various universities and NGOs.  Historically the cursor has always reappeared immediately.

If I shut my laptop computer down before all of the `R` files have finished running will this cause the `R` files to crash or otherwise not run to completion?

Is there a way I can get the cursor to reappear immediately in `PuTTY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have never seen this before when using clusters at various universities and NGOs. Historically the cursor has always reappeared immediately.

From what I know, the difference is that most clusters tell you to use special commands like `qsub` for batch job submission. These commands return instantly because they don't run the script immediately – they just add it to the queue and a separate system decides where and when to run your script.

On AWS, however, you don't have any of that – it's a completely plain Linux system. If you directly run a Bash script via `./myscript.sh` or `bash myscript.sh`, then it *does* run immediately right there in your terminal. And like with any other program that you run, the shell prompt won't reappear until the program is finished.

> If I shut my laptop computer down before all of the R files have finished running will this cause the R files to crash or otherwise not run to completion?

Yes, when a terminal is closed (i.e. when the connection is "hung up"), all processes running from it get a signal to exit. They might ignore it, but usually they exit immediately.

> Is there a way I can get the cursor to reappear immediately in PuTTY?

There are two most common options for long-running tasks on Linux:

1. Use Bash's job control, i.e. append `&` to run a command in background. For example:

   ```
   ./slowscript.sh &
   ```

   If you forgot to add the `&`, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> followed by the `bg` command to put an already-running program in background.

   Note that programs under job control will still get terminated when you close the SSH connection. To avoid this, you also need to `disown` each job – you will no longer be able to see its status, but it will also no longer be killed on hangup.
2. Use a "terminal multiplexer" such as *tmux* or *Screen*. Instead of dealing with batch jobs, they let you put a whole terminal in background.

   So you can first run `tmux` to create a "detachable" terminal, then start your R script from there, and while it's running press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd> to detach it.

   (Even if you forget to detach, it will happen automatically when disconnecting – the programs will remain running inside tmux.) Later you can use `tmux at[tach]` to reattach.
3. In some Linux distributions you can also use systemd to start background jobs. This feature first needs to be enabled with `sudo loginctl enable-linger $USER`.

   Once enabled, you can start background tasks using `systemd-run`:

   ```
   systemd-run --user --same-dir ./myscript.sh
   ```

   Later you can use `systemctl --user .....` to see the job's status.

Comment: This is very helpful.  Can tell me how to `disown` a job?  I can try to look it up.  Or do your Steps 2 & 3 describe how to `disown`?

Comment: Literally use the command `disown`, after putting the process in background. (Also, these are not steps 2 & 3, these are alternative methods 2 & 3.)

Comment: Other pages might also suggest using `nohup` to run the script; I keep forgetting it. It is very similar in effect to the first method described above ('script&' + 'disown').